# Activity is not start after adding put parcelable android

Tags: android, android-intent

I declared an arrayList and want to pass it between activites. However, the activity is not starting.

```
private ArrayList<CategoryItem> categoryArray = new ArrayList<CategoryItem>();
```

onClick:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CategoryViewActivity.class);

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("categoryList", categoryArray);

startActivity(i);
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

When I removed `i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("categoryList", categoryArray);`, it works fine.

in the logcat, I got:

```
E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: I think I know what's wrong now. There are images in the arraylist, so the categoryArray is too large to pass

Comment: look at my answer i was faced same problem. i have posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

First make `CategoryItem` impliment `Serializable`
and do this:

```
i.putExtra("categoryList", ( ArrayList<CategoryItem>) categoryArray );
```

and in another class (CategoryViewActivity) do:

```
ArrayList<CategoryItem> categoryArray = (ArrayList<CategoryItem>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("categoryList");
```

Comment: I am trying out your solution, it still has "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION". maybe the problem is how I wrote the images to parcel

Comment: are you using bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CategoryViewActivity.class);

Bundle bundle;
bundle.putParcelableArrayListExtra("categoryList", categoryArray);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```